# user/logout access denied v7.34

Tags: users, uri

Admin or normal user can not logout using `www.myswebsite.com/user/logout`

*An access denied* page is displayed and the user is still logged.

using `?q=user/logout` works.

It is not a rewrite problem, all other url are ok.

I have cleared the cache and deleted the cookies, tried on FF, IE & Chrome.

Any idea to investigate ?

Comment: Are you using fb functionality to your site ?

Comment: Nope, modules used are:
nagios, CKEditor, IMCE

Comment: Actually this issue occurred due to SESSION.

Comment: If you are using any custom module & hold the SESSION or any SESSION created in any module then first check & try to close that SESSION. Your issue will solved.

Comment: I have trash the session table, issue is still present.

Comment: Refer to this link : https://www.drupal.org/node/1022932#comment-4003886

Comment: I don't get why ?q=user/logout works and not /user/logout

I have no trace of the 403 for /user/logout into apache log??

http://pastebin.com/PuC65g7C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root cause. The Geocaching. I am in Australia and the server is in France. The missing of /user/logout into the apache log warns me. I have tested with a french proxy and everything is ok.

My provider offers Geocaching, the page looks to be cached.

I have purge the geocache and /user/logout works!!

The first hit of a 403 for /user/logout triggers the same problem.
This is easy to understand, when user/logout is success, the answer is a 302, nothing is added into the cache whereas a 403 is permanent so it is stored.

This explains why ?q=user/logout works, it is a query no caching is done.

**To summarize deactivate the geocaching.**

Answer (score 0):

Try different way

1. This works for me if I substitute the logged-in username for 'user', like this:

http://my_site/my_user/logout

ie:

http://example.com/jdoe/logout

2. this might be problem with not enabling clean url in your site go to

http://example.com/admin/config/search/clean-urls

enable clean url and check if its working

3. as you mentioned use http://example.com/user/logout will logout the current user section

Further readings:
logout problem - https://www.drupal.org/node/1572984

enabling clean url - https://www.drupal.org/node/1572984

access denied + logout - https://www.drupal.org/node/2192401

Comment: clean url is working without problem. Your two links are the same.

Comment: so you have clean url enabled and when user go to user/logout he is still logged in.

Comment: yes, as far I remember it was working. I have only change the css of my theme and the page content, nothing special.